# SQLite Flow Constructs in SQL?

Tags: sqlite, loops, for-loop, while-loop, procedural

With MSSQL, I can mix in case, if...then, and while constructs in my SQL code. Is anything similar available for SQLite? I have not seen anything on "mixing procedurally" with SQLite, anywhere.

Thanks.

Comment: SQLite does support temp tables, if that helps: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite doesn't have any loop syntax - `FOR` or `WHILE`.  `CASE` statements are supported rather than IF.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to load a csv file into a Celko-esque "nested set" table in SQLite. I need to keep track of temporary variables and etc. Need help thinking...