# sqlite insert error

Tags: sql, sqlite

I use Firefox plugin SQLite Manager execute my SQL:

```
    declare @id int
    declare @lon float
    declare @lat float
    set @id=5
    set @lon=118.476000
    set @lat=32.033720
    while @i<=10000
      begin
        INSERT INTO njdm 
          (ID,dalei,xiaolei,hanyi,level,longitude,latitude) 
        VALUES 
          (@id, 5, 10, "地名描述",1,@lon,@lat)

        set @id=@id+1
        set @lon=@lon+0.000010
        set @lat=@lat+0.000010
      end
```

And get the error:

```
    [ near "declare": syntax error ]
    Exception Name: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
    Exception Message: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)                          [mozIStorageConnection.createStatement]
```

any help?TIA!

Comment: `insert into njdm (ID,dalei,xiaolei,hanyi,level,longitude,latitude) VALUES (id, 5, 10, "地名描述",1,@lon,@lat)`, did you miss `@` before id?

Comment: sorry,my fault.But with @id, get the same error

Comment: it seems that the sqlite has no keyword declare, try to just remove them?

Comment: Both `declare` and `set` are not supported by sqlite i think.Then how can i insert lots of records into table?

Comment: This looks like MSSQL T-SQL, sqlite doesn't [support](http://www.sqlite.org/lang.html) a lot of that.

Comment: try to remove `set`, use `@var = value` directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite supports *only* SQL operations, it does not directly support variables, variable assignments, looping, or other program constructs.  You will need to write this code in some other language that supports those constructs, then send the commands to SQLite either by constructing dynamic SQL or by using one of the SQLite support libraries associated with your selected language.

Answer (score 0):

```
      declare @id int
        declare @lon float
        declare @lat float
        set @id=5
        set @lon=118.476000
        set @lat=32.033720
        while @id<=10000
          begin
            INSERT INTO njdm 
              (ID,dalei,xiaolei,hanyi,level,longitude,latitude) 
            VALUES 
              (@id, 5, 10, "地名描述",1,@lon,@lat)

            set @id=@id+1
            set @lon=@lon+0.000010
            set @lat=@lat+0.000010
          end

Note:  while @id<=10000 instead of  while @i<=10000
```

Comment: Thanks.But SQLite dont support `declare` and `set`. i'm trying insert with SQLite API.

Comment: set_var(var_name, value)  -- create or set existing variable 
get_var(var_name)  -- get value from variable 
del_var(var_name)  -- clear out variable

Comment: SELECT set_var('var1', 15);  -- set var1 to 15 
SELECT set_var('var2', a) FROM tab WHERE rowid=1;  -- set var2 to value from 
table 
SELECT a, b, c FROM tab WHERE a = get_var('var2');  -- select from table 
using variable 
SELECT del_var('var2'); -- delete variable

Answer (score 0):

SQLite [does not appear to support WHILE constructs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885702/sqlite-flow-constructs-in-sql). You might be able to [finagle a similar effect using extra tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370761/sqlite-loop-statements), but it's probably easier to offload some of the work to the application.